# How to initialize class properly? flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm adapting my app to run on web as well and as I need firebase real time database, remote config and storage, I see that for the web I should use `firebase` package instead.
As I use flutter_bloc/repository pattern I implemented the stub/abstract class/implementation classes pattern to switch repository depending on the platform.
So far so good everything on device app works just as before.

Now addressing the web app , I made a singleton class so I can call it and initialize a Firebase App once and then have access to all the services from any point in my app when running on web.

The problem I'm facing is that I get `only static members can be accessed in initializers` when initializing `Auth _firebaseAuth;` the web repository.
I tried initializing it both directly and in the class constructor (mimicking the device repository constructor commented above) using a method but I get the error both ways.
Ho do I initialize it properly?
As always thank you very much for you time and help.

This is the singleton:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';


class FirebaseWeb {
  // Singleton instance
  static final FirebaseWeb _singleton = FirebaseWeb._();

  // Singleton accessor
  static FirebaseWeb get instance => _singleton;

  // Completer is used for transforming synchronous code into asynchronous code.
  Completer<App> _dbOpenCompleter;

  // A private constructor. Allows us to create instances of AppDatabase
  // only from within the AppDatabase class itself.
  FirebaseWeb._();

  // Sembast database object
//  Database _database;

  // Database object accessor

  Future<App> get app async {
    // If completer is null, AppDatabaseClass is newly instantiated, so database is not yet opened
    if (_dbOpenCompleter == null) {
      _dbOpenCompleter = Completer();
      // Calling _openDatabase will also complete the completer with database instance
      _initializeApp();
    }
    // If the database is already opened, awaiting the future will happen instantly.
    // Otherwise, awaiting the returned future will take some time - until complete() is called
    // on the Completer in _openDatabase() below.
    return _dbOpenCompleter.future;
  }

  Future _initializeApp() async {
    initializeApp(
        name: 'xxx',
        apiKey: "xxx",
        authDomain: "xxx",
        databaseURL: "xxx",
        projectId: "xxx",
        storageBucket: "xxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxx",
        appId: "xxx");
    _dbOpenCompleter.complete();
  }
}
```

This is the web repository:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart';
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/authentication_bloc/fixit_user.dart';
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/platform_firebase_database/firebase_singleton.dart';
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/platform_user_repository/platform_user_repository_switcher.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class UserRepositoryWeb implements UserRepository {
//  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  Auth
      _firebaseAuth; // = _Auth() ;//only static members can be accessed in initializers

//  App app = FirebaseWeb.instance.app as App;
//  Future<App> get _app async => FirebaseWeb.instance.app;

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn; // = GoogleSignIn();

//  UserRepository({FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth, GoogleSignIn googleSignIn})
//      : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance,
//        _googleSignIn = googleSignIn ?? GoogleSignIn();

  UserRepositoryWeb({Auth firebaseAuth, GoogleSignIn googleSignIn})
      : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ??
            _Auth(), //only static members can be accessed in initializers
        _googleSignIn = googleSignIn ?? GoogleSignIn();

  void _Auth() async {
    App app = FirebaseWeb.instance.app as App;
    _firebaseAuth = app.auth();
  }

//  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    print('signInWithGoogle() started');
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    print('GoogleUser is : $googleUser');
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
//    final AuthCredential credential = await GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
//        idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
    final OAuthCredential credential = await GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        googleAuth.idToken, googleAuth.accessToken);
    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
//    return _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  }

//  Future<void> signInWithCredential({String email, String password}) {
//    return _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
//        email: email, password: password);
//  }
  Future<void> signInWithCredential({String email, String password}) {
    return _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

//  Future<void> signUp({String email, String password}) {
//    return _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
//        email: email, password: password);
//  }
  Future<void> signUp({String email, String password}) {
    return _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return Future.wait([
      _firebaseAuth.signOut(),
      _googleSignIn.signOut(),
    ]);
  }

  Future<bool> isSignedIn() async {
//    final currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    final currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    return currentUser != null;
  }

  Future<FixitUser> getUser() async {
    String displayName = (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser).displayName;
    String email = (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser).email;
    String uid = (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser).uid;
    String photoUrl = (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser).photoURL;
    String phoneNumber = (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser).phoneNumber;
    FixitUser user = FixitUser(
        name: displayName ?? '',
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber ?? '',
        uid: uid,
        photoUrl: photoUrl ?? '');
    return (user);
  }
}

UserRepository getUserRepository() => UserRepositoryWeb();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a few tries I finally fine tuned the singleton and the web implementation class. In my singleton I was returning a `Future<App>`, that would make using it less straight forward (see commented out parts in web repository) than returning an `App`, also as I have yet to master `Completer()` I was having a few difficulties debugging the code so I decided not to use it.

## Singleton:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';

class FirebaseWeb {
  // Singleton instance
  static final FirebaseWeb _singleton = FirebaseWeb._();

  // Singleton accessor
  static FirebaseWeb get instance => _singleton;

  // Completer is used for transforming synchronous code into asynchronous code.
  Completer<App> _dbOpenCompleter;

  // A private constructor. Allows us to create instances of AppDatabase
  // only from within the AppDatabase class itself.
  FirebaseWeb._();

  static App _app;
  // Database object accessor

  App get app {
    print('firebase get app called ');
    print('_app is $_app');
    if (_app != null) {
      return _app;
    } else {
      print('initialize app');
      _app = initializeApp(
          apiKey: "xxx",
          authDomain: "xxx",
          databaseURL: "xxx",
          projectId: "xxx",
          storageBucket: "xxx",
          messagingSenderId: "xxx",
          appId: "xxx");
      return _app;
    }
  }

}
```

## Web repository:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:firebaseblocwebstub/authentication_bloc/app_user.dart';
import 'package:firebaseblocwebstub/firebase_singleton.dart';
import 'package:firebaseblocwebstub/platform_user_repository/platform_user_repository_switcher.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class UserRepositoryWeb implements UserRepositorySwitcher {
  App firebase = FirebaseWeb.instance.app;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    print('signInWithGoogle() started');
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    print('GoogleUser is : $googleUser');
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final OAuthCredential credential = await GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        googleAuth.idToken, googleAuth.accessToken);
    // singleton retunrning Future<App>
//    await firebase.then((firebase) {
//      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
//      return;
//    });
//    return firebase.then((firebase) {
//      return firebase.auth().currentUser;
//    });

    await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
  }

  Future<void> signInWithCredential({String email, String password}) {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    // singleton retunrning Future<App>
//    return firebase.then((firebase) {
//      return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
//    });
  }

  Future<void> signUp({String email, String password}) {
    return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    // singleton retunrning Future<App>
//    return firebase.then((firebase) {
//      return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
//    });
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return Future.wait([
      firebase.auth().signOut(),
// singleton retunrning Future<App>
//      firebase.then((firebase) {
//        firebase.auth().signOut();
//      }),
      _googleSignIn.signOut(),
    ]);
  }

  Future<bool> isSignedIn() async {
    final currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    return currentUser != null;
    // singleton retunrning Future<App>
//    User firebaseUser = firebase.then((firebase) {
//      return firebase.auth().currentUser;
//    }) as User;
//    return firebaseUser != null;
  }

  Future<FixitUser> getUser() async {
    // singleton retunrning Future<App>
//    User firebaseUser = firebase.then((firebase) {
//      return firebase.auth().currentUser;
//    }) as User;
//
//    FixitUser user = FixitUser(
//        name: firebaseUser.displayName ?? '',
//        email: firebaseUser.email,
//        phoneNumber: firebaseUser.phoneNumber ?? '',
//        uid: firebaseUser.uid,
//        photoUrl: firebaseUser.photoURL ?? '');
//    return (user);
//  }
    String displayName = (firebase.auth().currentUser).displayName;
    String email = (firebase.auth().currentUser).email;
    String uid = (firebase.auth().currentUser).uid;
    String photoUrl = (firebase.auth().currentUser).photoURL;
    String phoneNumber = (firebase.auth().currentUser).phoneNumber;

    FixitUser user = FixitUser(
        name: displayName ?? '',
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber ?? '',
        uid: uid,
        photoUrl: photoUrl ?? '');
    return (user);
  }
}

UserRepositorySwitcher getUserRepository() => UserRepositoryWeb();
```